# How to get rid of webkit Gamepad API deadzone?

Tags: gamepad-api

I'm using gamepad api[1](https://www.w3.org/TR/gamepad/) to read controller axis value in a web based game, but found that the gamepad API always applies a certain amount of "deadzone" around the center of each axis, where the value doesn't change even when the gimbal on the controller moves. I understand this is useful for common home use controllers, but this is really undesirable for precision focus controllers. How do you disable this auto applied deadzone in webkit?

Comment: Are you sure this is being applied in the user agent?  I don't see this behavior listed in the spec anyway, so it could probably be a bug report.

Comment: Yeah I'm pretty sure, I also tried using WebHID api to read the data, no deadzone applied around the center. Also didn't find anything in the spec, that's why I'm confused.

Comment: I would expect the Gamepad API to use a different underlying OS API than straight HID.  In Windows, for example, you can configure the deadzone.  If you're sure it's coming from Webkit, I'd recommend filing a bug report.  But, I'd still be suspicious that this is coming from somewhere else.  Seems strange.  Then again, there are a lot of strange things in Webkit.  :-)